# Mi codigo no devuelve el valor real de el QWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, pygal

Buenas noches tengo el siguiente codigo: 
El error que se me presenta es que al momento de imprimir el tamaño de `self.widget.width()` me arroja el valor de 100 mientras que en el QT Designer me muestrta que el valor es de 450

El segundo error es que al pasarle el valor al grafico utilizando `visual.pygal.Line(width=self.widget.width())`, mantiene ese valor estatico y no cambia el valor a la par que el widget aumenta o decrementa el valor de su width()

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import pygal
from pygal.style import BlueStyle


class nGrafico(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("n_grafico.ui",self)
        Self.graf (1,2,3,4,5,6)

    def graf(self,l,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5):

        print(self.widget.width())

        visual = pygal.Line(style=BlueStyle,title=u"Reporte de Internet",legend_at_bottom=True)
        visual.x_labels=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
        visual.add("Internet Matutino", l)
        visual.add("Internet Vespertino", l1)

        data = visual.render_data_uri()
        self.widget.setUrl(QUrl(data))

        self.graf2(l2,l3)
        self.graf3(l4,l5)

    def graf2(self,l,l1):
        visual = pygal.Line(style=BlueStyle,title="Reporte de Recargas",legend_at_bottom=True)
        visual.x_labels=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]

        visual.add("Recargas Matutino", l)
        visual.add("Recargas Vespertino", l1)

        data = visual.render_data_uri()
        self.widget2.setUrl(QUrl(data))

    def graf3(self,l,l1):
        visual = pygal.Line(style=BlueStyle,title="Reporte de Sistema",legend_at_bottom=True)
        visual.x_labels=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]

        visual.add("Sistema Matutino", l)
        visual.add("Sistema Vespertino", l1)

        data = visual.render_data_uri()
        self.widget3.setUrl(QUrl(data))



#app = QApplication([])
#n = nGrafico()
#n.show()
#app.exec_()
```

Archivo .ui.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <ui version="4.0">
         <class>MainWindow</class>
         <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>0</x>
            <y>0</y>
            <width>875</width>
            <height>581</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="windowTitle">
           <string>MainWindow</string>
          </property>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
           <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
            <property name="leftMargin">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <property name="topMargin">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <property name="rightMargin">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <property name="bottomMargin">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <property name="spacing">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <item row="1" column="1">
             <widget class="QWebEngineView" name="widget4" native="true"/>
            </item>
            <item row="0" column="1">
             <widget class="QWebEngineView" name="widget2" native="true"/>
            </item>
            <item row="1" column="0">
             <widget class="QWebEngineView" name="widget3" native="true"/>
            </item>
            <item row="0" column="0">
             <widget class="QWebEngineView" name="widget" native="true"/>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
         </widget>
         <customwidgets>
          <customwidget>
           <class>QWebEngineView</class>
           <extends>QWidget</extends>
           <header>PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets</header>
           <container>1</container>
          </customwidget>
         </customwidgets>
         <resources/>
         <connections/>
        </ui>
```

Comment: ¿En qué momento llamas a `graf(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **El error que se me presenta es que al momento de imprimir el tamaño de
>   self.widget.width() me arroja el valor de 100 mientras que en el QT
>   Designer me muestrta que el valor es de 450**

El tamaño del widget que usa el layout es el sizeHint() y depende del contenido, por cuestiones de eficiencia Qt no actualiza los items antes de mostrarlos por lo que el tamaño de los widget son diferentes antes y despues de mostrarse. Tu estas calculando el tamaño del widget antes de mostrarse sin que el layout haga su trabajo, y en el caso de Qt Designer va a cargat el widget y mostrarlo por lo tanto el layout ya hizo su trabajo.

Si quieres obtener el tamaño correcto debes mostrar el widget primero:

```
self.show()
print(self.widget.width())
```

> **el valor al grafico utilizando visual.pygal.Line(width=self.widget.width()), mantiene ese valor
>   estatico y no cambia el valor a la par que el widget aumenta o
>   decrementa el valor de su width()**

Pues eso es de esperar ya que nunca le señalas al item de pygal que la ventana ha cambiado de tamaño, los items de pygal tienen el tamaño que se les establecio inicialmente, la solución es que cada vez que se cambia el tamaño establecerlos en el item de pygal, y despues generar la nueva url para ello debemos sobreescribir el método resizeEvent() del QWebEngineView, asi que la solucion es promover el widget para ello creamos el widget personalizado:

**pygalview.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import pygal
from pygal.style import BlueStyle


class PyGalView(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def add_item(self, item):
        setattr(self, "item", item)
        url = item.render_data_uri()
        self.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(url))

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if hasattr(self, "item"):
            item = getattr(self, "item")
            item.width = self.size().width()
            item.height = self.size().height()
            url = item.render_data_uri()
            self.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        super(PyGalView, self).resizeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import random

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    visual = pygal.Line(style=BlueStyle,title=u"Reporte de Internet",legend_at_bottom=True)
    visual.x_labels= list(range(1, 32))
    l, l1 = [[random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(30)] for _ in range(2)]
    visual.add("Internet Matutino", l)
    visual.add("Internet Vespertino", l1)
    w = PyGalView()
    w.add_item(visual)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Editamos el .ui para que utilice el PyGalView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>875</width>
    <height>581</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="PyGalView" name="widget4"/>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <widget class="PyGalView" name="widget2"/>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="PyGalView" name="widget3"/>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="PyGalView" name="widget"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>PyGalView</class>
   <extends>QWebEngineView</extends>
   <header location="global">pygalview</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, uic
import pygal
from pygal.style import BlueStyle
import random


class nGrafico(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("n_grafico.ui", self)
        values = [[random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(30)] for _ in range(6)]
        self.graf(*values)

    def graf(self, l, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5):
        visual = pygal.Line(style=BlueStyle,title=u"Reporte de Internet",legend_at_bottom=True)
        visual.x_labels = list(range(1, 32))
        visual.add("Internet Matutino", l)
        visual.add("Internet Vespertino", l1)
        self.widget.add_item(visual)
        self.graf2(l2,l3)
        self.graf3(l4,l5)

    def graf2(self, l, l1):
        visual = pygal.Line(style=BlueStyle,title="Reporte de Recargas",legend_at_bottom=True)
        visual.x_labels = list(range(1, 32))
        visual.add("Recargas Matutino", l)
        visual.add("Recargas Vespertino", l1)
        self.widget2.add_item(visual)

    def graf3(self,l,l1):
        visual = pygal.Line(style=BlueStyle,title="Reporte de Sistema",legend_at_bottom=True)
        visual.x_labels = list(range(1, 32))
        visual.add("Sistema Matutino", l)
        visual.add("Sistema Vespertino", l1)
        self.widget3.add_item(visual)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    n = nGrafico()
    n.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

```
├── main.py
├── n_grafico.ui
└── pygalview.py
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]